# Styling multiple Countdown dates

Tags: jquery, css, countdown

I just want to create a page with countdowns to multiple events, but somehow it does not format correctly IDs number 12 and 13.

How it looks:

[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>


<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Countdown</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.countdown.css">

<style type="text/css">
#defaultCountdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({since: new Date(2010, 12-1, 25)}); 
    $('#12').countdown({since: new Date(2011, 12-1, 25)}); 
    $('#13').countdown({since: new Date(2012, 12-1, 25)}); 
});
</script>

</head>


<body>
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
<div id="12"></div>
<div id="13"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: How do you expect it to style them? You've only provided a style for #defaultCountdown.

Comment: It would be great if they could all look the same (like the first one). I have tried adding #12 { width: 240px; height: 45px; } and #13 { width: 240px; height: 45px; } , but it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them styled the same, assign them all a class, and style by class:

```
<style type="text/css">
.countdown { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
</style>
```

and

```
<body>
<div id="defaultCountdown" class="countdown"></div>
<div id="12" class="countdown"></div>
<div id="13" class="countdown"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css">
     #defaultCountdown, #12, #13 { width: 240px; height: 45px; }
 </style>
```

should do the trick. Of course it depends what is in your external stylesheet, too.